# In python, is it possible to fetch variable value, where the variable name is passed as a function argument

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to fetch a variable value by passing the variable name into a calling function.
My intention is to get the variable value based on the variable name passed as parameter.

```
class myConfigConstants():
    Name = "XYZ"
    Address = "abcd"
    Age = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = ""

    def fetch_myConfigConstants(self, strVariableName: str):
        self.value = myConfigConstants.strVariableName
        print(self.value)
        return self.value

mc = myConfigConstants()
mc.fetch_myConfigConstants('Name')
```

Expected output:
XYZ

This results in error:
AttributeError: type object 'myConfigConstants' has no attribute 'strVariableName'

I understand that it is looking for the exact attribute, but how to make passed parameter name resolves into actual attribute at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getattr` function.

```
getattr(self, strVariableName)
```

In your code,

```
...
def fetch_myConfigConstants(self, strVariableName: str):
    self.value = getattr(self, strVariableName)
    print(self.value)
    return self.value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getattr` for this.

```
self.value = getattr(myConfigConstants, strVariableName)
```